# await GetByteArrayAsync in asp.net not returning

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

The following code just hangs when called from an ASP.NET app:

```
private async Task<XPathNavigator> UspsCreateAndPostRequest(string sUrl)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  byte[] urlContents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(sUrl);
  string sResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(urlContents);
  ... //more code to return XPathNavigator object based on response
}
```

If I change to following it works fine:

```
private async Task<XPathNavigator> UspsCreateAndPostRequest(string sUrl)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  byte[] urlContents = null;
  var task = Task.Run(async () => { urlContents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(strUrl); });
  task.Wait();
  string sResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(urlContents);
  ... //more code to return XPathNavigator object based on response
}
```

Is the fact that method signature return is a Task<XPathNavigator> causing the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Don't call `.Wait()` on tasks, it causes deadlocks.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain OP says it is the working version :)

Comment: @Eser because somewhere higher up the chain there is a `.Wait()` on the task that is returned from `UspsCreateAndPostRequest`. Because he wrapped it inside a `Task.Run` he lost the execution context, that is why it works. Doing a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` would achave the same goal with less resources (but it would be even better to fix the wait higher up on the chain)

Comment: I couldn't find any other .Wait() higher up the chain. I took that one Wait() out and replaced with .ConfigureAwait(false) call, but still hung. Also tried adding .ConfigureAwait(false) to everything higher up in the stack that originally made the call to UspsCreateAndPostRequest, but still not working. There is a lot of code to work through though and I'll keep checking. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Somewhere higher up the call stack there is a `.Wait()` being performed on the task that is returned from `UspsCreateAndPostRequest`.

Because you wrapped the call inside a `Task.Run` you lost the execution context, that is why it works. Doing

```
private async Task<XPathNavigator> UspsCreateAndPostRequest(string sUrl)
{
  HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
  byte[] urlContents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(sUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);
  string sResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(urlContents);
  ... //more code to return XPathNavigator object based on response
}
```

would achieve the same goal with less resources (but it would be even better to fix the wait higher up on the chain).

Comment: I just tried replacing those 3 lines with "byte[] urlContents = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(sUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);", but still hangs and doesn't return.

Comment: Follow the callstack up, every level needs `.ConfigureAwait(false);` added to it all the way up.

Comment: Is there a post or article somewhere that explains this in more detail? The part about losing the execution context...